# How can I join specific tuples in my list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to generate a list of tuples which contain a state (`SPACE`, `WRITE`, `SYMBOL`, etc) and a token ( , `+`, `[A-Za-z0-9]*`).

My input is a string of tokens:

> +adfe3 +212daeE

I'm using this statement at this time to convert my input string to a list of tuples containing the state and token:

```
result = [(conversion_from_token_to_state(t),t) for t in stringOfTokens]
```

Which results in:

> [('WRITE', '+'), ('SYMBOL', 'a'), ('SYMBOL', 'd'), ('SYMBOL', 'f'), ('SYMBOL', 'e'), ('SYMBOL', '3'), ('SPACE', ' '), ('WRITE', '+'), ('SYMBOL', '2'), ('SYMBOL', '1'), ('SYMBOL', '2'), ('SYMBOL', 'd'), ('SYMBOL', 'a'), ('SYMBOL', 'e'), ('SYMBOL', 'E')]

How can I reduce these multiples of sequential `('SYMBOL', 'a')` tuples into a single `('SYMBOL', 'adfe3')`?

My guess is that I would need to add some `if else` construct to my list comprehension but can't figure out how to make it only handle the characters/numbers and let the others alone.

[Itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) seems to be the answer but I don't see how this can be such applied that only the consecutive SYMBOL tuples are concatenated into one.

Background for the question: these are (states,transition tokens) in a statemachine and as such it could be possible that only some tokens (in this case `SYMBOL`) need to be grouped for a state transition but multiple `WRITE` or `SPACE` may occur without the need for grouping.

Comment: I think this cannot be done by a simple list comprehension, as it requires a state, in the sense that different actions are needed dependent on if the previous token was a `SYMBOL` or something else. It is not hard to handle with a `while` loop keeping a state, but it it is beyond the capabilities of a (simple) list comprehension. (If creative, it can be handled by a generator *and* a list comprehension, but it is questionable if that is better...)

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track. Try this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

tokens = [('WRITE', '+'), ('SYMBOL', 'a'), ('SYMBOL', 'd'), ('SYMBOL', 'f'), ('SYMBOL', 'e'), ('SYMBOL', '3'), ('SPACE', ' '), ('WRITE', '+'), ('SYMBOL', '2'), ('SYMBOL', '1'), ('SYMBOL', '2'), ('SYMBOL', 'd'), ('SYMBOL', 'a'), ('SYMBOL', 'e'), ('SYMBOL', 'E')]

simplified_token = [(k, ''.join(list(x[1] for x in g))) for k, g  in groupby(tokens, key=itemgetter(0))]

print(simplified_token)
```

Output:

```
[('WRITE', '+'), ('SYMBOL', 'adfe3'), ('SPACE', ' '), ('WRITE', '+'), ('SYMBOL', '212daeE')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the import statements, didn't now that. It works indeed so thanks. I don't get how it works though so I'll be studying your answer.

Comment: This, however, does not group only `SYMBOL`s into one. Consecutive `WRITE`s (or anything else) will also be grouped together. As I interpreted the last sentence of the original post, this is not the wanted behavior?

Comment: @JohanL I think because there is never an occurrence of adjacent `WRITE` tuples, they weren't mentioned as an example.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the example indeed. It would be best if it would only group the SYMBOLs as it could be possible that a consecutive write would be valid without the need for grouping

Answer (score 0):

You can make the key function for `itertools.groupby` output a new `object` instance if the first item isn't `SYMBOL` so that only the `SYMBOL` items would be grouped together, since no two `object` instances can be equal to each other:

```
[next(g) if k else ('SYMBOL', ''.join(i for _, i in g))
    for k, g in groupby(stringOfTokens, key=lambda t: t[0] != 'SYMBOL' and object())]
```

This returns:

```
[('WRITE', '+'), ('SYMBOL', 'adfe3'), ('SPACE', ' '), ('WRITE', '+'), ('SYMBOL', '212daeE')]
```